# Partial Differentiation of $\frac 00$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let:
$$f(x,y)=x^2y\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),\ x\neq0$$
$$f(x,y)=0, \ x=0$$
Partial differentiation is obvious for $x\neq0$, however, for $x = 0$ and the derivative over $x$, one gets:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,y)}{h}$$
which is not constant $= 0$.
Do I need to use L'Hospital? If yes differentiating over which variable?
I'm new to this topic.

Comment: When you compute partial derivatives with respect to $x$, the value of $y$ is held constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $x = 0$, the definition of partial derivative gives us
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0, y) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h, y) - f(0, y)}{h}\\
= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2y\sin(y/h) - 0}{h}\\
= \lim_{h\to 0}hy\sin(y/h) = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,y)}h=\lim_{h\to0}hy\sin\frac yh=0$ since $y$ is (constant) finite and $\sin\frac yh$ is bounded.